# Setting PHP extension_dir path in php.ini not working as i expected

Tags: path, lubuntu, php7

When i set the `extension_dir` in php.ini and use the full path like this, it works

```
extension_dir = "/home/appie/Bureaublad/astroapp/phpdesktop-linux-72.1/ext"
extension = "sweph.so"
```

But if i do:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension = "sweph.so"
```

or

```
extension_dir = "./ext"
extension = "sweph.so"
```

Then it doesn't. For my program, i can't use full paths since the software can be placed in other directorys. So how to set the right path?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple

```
extension_dir = "./"
```

Should do the trick inside Linux as per the default PHP.ini file.

Comment: That is what i expected to and also what i have tried, but for some reason it doesn't work this way in php.ini